# How to order the columns in a Pandas Dataframe using a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a list of strings, e.g. (`str_list = list('ad','gf','hl','bc')`) and I want to use that list to arrange the order of the columns in a pandas dataframe (e.g. Columns: ad gf hl bc).  The header values in the dataframe correspond to the values in my list, but are ordered randomly.  Is there a way to use the list as an index for ordering the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the list to select the columns in the wanted order:

```
df_ordered = df[str_list]
```

This feature is called "*smart indexing*."

Comment: Thanks!  Now I'm getting the following error: "ValueError: cannot label index with a null key"  Any idea why?

Comment: Please update your question accordingly, include the complete error message.